# MinGW Doesn't Generate an Object File When Compiling

Tags: c++, binary, g++, mingw

I've just bought a new laptop for me on the travel, then on my free time, I've started to test [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) on it by trying to compile my own OS that is written in C++, then I've created all the files needed and the `kernel.cpp`:

```
extern "C" void _main(struct multiboot_data* mbd, unsigned int magic);
 
void _main( struct multiboot_data* mbd, unsigned int magic )
{
   char * boot_loader_name =(char*) ((long*)mbd)[16];
 
   /* Print a letter to screen to see everything is working: */
   unsigned char *videoram = (unsigned char *) 0xb8000;
   videoram[0] = 65; /* character 'A' */
   videoram[1] = 0x07; /* forground, background color. */
}
```

And tried to compile it with g++

> G:> g++ -o C:\kernel.o -c kernel.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Werror -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
> kernel.cpp: In function `void _main(multiboot_data*, unsigned int)':
> kernel.cpp:8: warning: unused variable 'boot_loader_name'
> kernel.cpp: At global scope:
> kernel.cpp:4: warning: unused parameter 'magic'
>
> G:>

But it don't create any binary file at `C:/`>.

What can I do?

Comment: Why not try a simplest example: 1) create somewhere a file like `1.cpp` containing just `int main() {return 0;}` (and the empty line at the end); 2) run `g++ -c 1.cpp -Wall` in that folder; and then see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't create the file because you have `-Werror` enabled. The warnings you're getting about unused variables are counting as errors, so compilation gets aborted. Just comment them out for the moment:

```
void _main( struct multiboot_data* mbd, unsigned int /* magic */ )
{
    // char * boot_loader_name =(char*) ((long*)mbd)[16];
    // ...
}
```

And it should build fine. Also, shouldn't `_main()` be declared as just `main()` and then allowed to be "mangled" into `_main()` by the compiler? **Edit:** You probably also want to be using `-c` to skip the linking phase, assuming you just want the object files.

Comment: Ah, right, `extern "C"` takes care of that. Silly rabbit. Plus it's been a while since I looked at the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating the `.o` file in a local directory first? What result did you get?

Comment: Yeah, and I still got nothing.

Comment: @Nathan: that's strange. Try to compile an empty `main` into an executable, does mingw create it ?

Comment: @Nathan: and then with the same commandline invocation your .cpp file creates nothing? no new files at all?

Comment: @Eli: If I do a Hello World(using `cout`, `#include`...) it compiles nice, but if I try to compile my simple kernel, I don't create anything.

Comment: @Nathan: could it be because your kernel doesn't have a `main` function?

Comment: I think no, because when I was compiling it on my Linux machine(at my home) it compiles nice.

Comment: Also, trying to compile a empty `_main` don't create a object file.

Answer (score 1):

C:\ is usually blocked for writing on Vista and 7, since it's considered a very sensitive location, and you have to run as administrator to be allowed to do that (as in, *explicitly* launching the command prompt or g++ with admin rights). The same should apply if you're running on a "regular" (non-admin) user account, even in XP.

Perhaps that's what's happening to you?

Comment: I've changed for `G:` and I still got nothing.